# multiple forms in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp

We have two different forms in one jsp page one for submission and one that approves.
The code is:

```
<%if(rs.getInt("approve")==0) {%>

    <form method="get" action="storecomment3.jsp">
        Comments:<br>
        <textarea  name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
        <br> 
        <input type="hidden" name="article" value="<%=realname%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="Username" value="<%=request.getParameter("Username")%>">
        <input type="hidden" name="Password" value="<%=request.getParameter("Password")%>">
        <input type=submit value="Submit">
    </form>
    <%} %>
    <%if(rs.getInt("approve")==0) {%>

    <form name="form1" action="usermain.jsp">
    <input type=button value="Approve" onclick="validate()">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<%=request.getParameter("user")%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Username" value="<%=request.getParameter("Username")%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Password" value="<%=request.getParameter("Password")%>">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate()
        {
            <% 
                r1.updateInt("approve", 1);
                r1.updateRow();

                %>
                document.form1.submit();
        }
    </script>
    </form>
```

The problem with the code is that when the submit button in the first form is clicked, the validate function is also getting executed which should not be happening!
Is there anything wrong with the code or the script?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few possible problems here.

First, your condition `rs.getInt("approve")==0` appears twice, perhaps one of them should be `!=0`?

Also it seems odd that you put `r1.updateInt("approve", 1);` and `r1.updateRow();` inside the JS function. That code gets executed server side(!) as soon as the condition (`rs.getInt("approve")==0`) is met, no user interaction required.

Comment: those are two resultsets actually both contain the same rows but one is prepared statement so I wasn't able to make the resultset updatable :/

Comment: Thanks thanks the problem was with the two resultsets